# Installed package not accessible in nexts Gitlab pipelines jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab

I'm trying to build and push my Dockerfile through Gitlab pipeline, here is my specification.

gitlab-ci.yaml:

```
stages:
  - prepare
  - login
  - build
  - push

image: python:3.11-alpine

variables:
  PROJECT_NAME: jenkins
  AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY: $AWS_ECR_REGISTRY/ecommerce_$PROJECT_NAME
  ENVIRONMENT: stage
  VERSION: 1.0.0

Prepare:
  stage: prepare
  only:
    - stage
    - prod
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache docker
    - pip install awscli
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set region $AWS_REGION

Docker Login:
  stage: login
  only:
    - stage
    - prod
  script:
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ECR_REGISTRY

Docker Build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - stage
    - prod
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT -t $AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY:latest .
    - docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT -t $AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY:$VERSION .

Docker Push:
  stage: push
  only:
    - stage
    - prod
  script:
    - docker push $AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY:latest
    - docker push $AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY:$VERSION
```

First job finish successfully but when i'm trying to login/build/deploy get following error, build:

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ECR_REGISTRY
/bin/sh: eval: line 140: aws: not found
/bin/sh: eval: line 140: docker: not found
```

Anyone could help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Please add sample details of your build and push stages as well. I can help you out with a overall solution to get this to work the way you want to. Please note that each stage is executed in a different container and if you install any new capability(like aws cli) it wont be accessible across stages as each stage is isolated(different containers).

Comment: So, how can i have same container on each job ? Rerun same commands on each job ? Artifacts ?

Comment: Then instead of image: python:3.11-alpine you will have to build a custom image which has python and aws cli and then use such an image for each job, then aws cli will be resent in each job container. But if you are want to ecr login, then you will have to do this in before_script template and extend that template in each stage

Comment: I can give you a work around if you dont want to create a custom image. Let me know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirement here is my suggestion

You can use hidden jobs that start with `"."` as templates for reusable configuration with `"extends"`

Below the `".prepare"` template can be extended in your build and deploy jobs and use `before_script` to define an array of commands that should run before each job’s `script` commands

```
stages:
  - build
  - push

image: python:3.11-alpine

variables:
  PROJECT_NAME: jenkins
  AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY: $AWS_ECR_REGISTRY/ecommerce_$PROJECT_NAME
  ENVIRONMENT: stage
  VERSION: 1.0.0

.prepare:
  before_script: |
    apk add --no-cache docker
    pip install awscli
    aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    aws configure set region $AWS_REGION
    aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ECR_REGISTRY

Docker Build:
  stage: build
  extends: .prepare
  only:
    - stage
    - prod
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT -t $AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY:latest .
    - docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT -t $AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY:$VERSION .

Docker Push:
  stage: push
  extends: .prepare
  only:
    - stage
    - prod
  script:
    - docker push $AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY:latest
    - docker push $AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY:$VERSION
```